# iPhone SOAP Web Services - Sample code on how to use the parsed code from wsdl2objc?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wsdl, parsing, sample

Is there any other documentation available at [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/)

besides the Usage Instructions?. The documentation is very limited, it may be because I have never used a wsdl parser before, in that case does anyone have any recommending reading for this?. If someone could please provide some sample code or link to a tutorial, on how to use what is parsed, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

-Oscar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://brismith66.blogspot.com/2010/05/iphone-development-accesing-soap.html